# Jenkins - export a scripted pipeline into a shared lib

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We have a few similar apps that are deployed with a *scripted* pipeline which is basically C&P over all apps. I would like to move the whole pipeline into a Jenkins shared lib as hinted in the [Jenkins docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-a-more-structured-dsl).

So let's suppose that I have the following "pipeline" in `var/standardSpringPipeline.groovy`:

```
#!groovy

def call() {

  node {
    echo "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
  }
}
```

Then - the Jenkins file:

```
@Library('my-jenkins-lib@master') _

standardSpringPipeline

echo "Bye!"
```

Unfortunately this does not work for a reason that I do not understand. The Jenkins output is similar:

```
> git fetch --no-tags --progress ssh://git@***.com:7999/log/my-jenkins-lib.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Checking out Revision 28900d4ed5bcece9451655f6f1b9a41a76256629 (master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 28900d4ed5bcece9451655f6f1b9a41a76256629
Commit message: "NOJIRA: ...."
 > git rev-list --no-walk 28900d4ed5bcece9451655f6f1b9a41a76256629 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] echo
Bye!
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Any clue why this does not work (see the output above) and what is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For no-arg methods, you cannot use optional parenthesis. From the [Groovy documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_optional_parentheses) (emphasis mine):

> Method calls can omit the parentheses if there is at least one parameter and there is no ambiguity:
>
> ```
> println 'Hello World'
> def maximum = Math.max 5, 10
> ```
>
> **Parentheses are required for method calls without parameters or
>   ambiguous method calls:**
>
> ```
> println() 
> println(Math.max(5, 10))
> ```

The `standardSpringPipeline` behaves like a method because of how it is compiled. If you add a `echo "$standardSpringPipeline"` it is a bit clearer that it is a compiled class that can be invoked.

To address your issue, just add parenthesis to the call:

```
standardSpringPipeline()
```

Comment: That's so embarrassing :-) 10x.